# Modifying the python script to ensure if it copies data from all stations instead of copying from only one station

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains weather data from 7 stations in the format below. This is the file to which I would like to append new data. This text file has each line with a date (YYYYDOY, for example, 2022001 denotes January 1st, 2022)followed by values (one decimal point padded with zero to ensure there are three values before the decimal point, e.g., 001.0002.5 are values for two stations, the first station has a value of 1.0 and the second station has a value of 2.5)for seven weather stations without spaces.

[image: file formatting]

I am trying to read new weather data from multiple new tab-separated text files. Each file holds data for one station (the first column is year followed by day, data variable 1, variable 2, variable 3), reformat it to make a new file compatible with the existing old data file, and append it to the old data file.

**Script:** Below is the script I tried. With this code, I can do everything but have one particular issue.

**Problem:** The problem is that the new weather data from only one station is copied to all seven stations.

**Expectation:** I expect to copy data from all seven stations.

Link to files: https://tcu.box.com/s/21o0cobauctubdnewnrrore6bwkomlrg

```
year0=2023 #first year to start new data
nWeatherStationsT=7
nWeatherStationsP=7

def makeSwatInput(txtOldData,txtNewData,txtfout,TorP):
    if TorP=='T': nWeatherStations=nWeatherStationsT
    else: nWeatherStations=nWeatherStationsP
    
    fin=open(txtOldData,'r') #read old weather data
    dataOld=fin.readlines()
    fin.close()

    fin=open(txtNewData,'r') #read new weather data
    dataNew=fin.readlines()
    fin.close()

#reformat new weather data
    for row in dataNew:
        line=row.split()
        year=int(line[0])
        day=int(line[1])

        if TorP=='T': #temperature
        
            if(float(line[2])>-99) : weather=str('%.1f' % float(line[3])).zfill(5)
            else: weather='-99.0'
            if(float(line[3])>-99) : weather=weather+str('%.1f' % float(line[2])).zfill(5)
            else: weather=weather+'-99.0'
        elif TorP=='P': #precip     
            if(float(line[4])>-99) : weather=str('%.1f' % float(line[4])).zfill(5)
            else: weather='-99.0'
        else: os.exit() #error

        lineOut=str(year0+year-1).zfill(4) + str(day).zfill(3) #year and day
        for i in range(nWeatherStations):                
            lineOut+=weather #fill in the weather for 7 stations

        dataOld.append(lineOut+'\n')

#save the data
    fout=open(txtfout,'w') #write weather data
    fout.writelines(dataOld)
    fout.close()
        
    return
```

Comment: What is the format of the input/output files?  Give *text* (not image) examples of both including examples of current and desired output files.

Comment: I have edited the question explaining the data format.

Comment: That part was understood. Please add actual text examples of the files themselves that work with the code.  Review the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Thank you. I included the link to the data files.

Comment: The script does `+= weather` in a loop, did you intend `weather` to be different in each iteration? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP needs to explain the data files better, but I think this is what they want.

It collects year/day data from all 7 files to compile an output line and appears to work with the given linked files:

```py
import csv

year0 = 2023  # first year to start new data
nWeatherStationsT = 7
nWeatherStationsP = 7

def makeSwatInput(txtOldData, txtNewData, txtfout, TorP):
    if TorP == 'T':
        nWeatherStations = nWeatherStationsT
    else:
        nWeatherStations = nWeatherStationsP

    with open(txtOldData) as fin:  # read old weather data
        dataOld = fin.readlines()

    # Collect data from all 7 stations coerced into correct types.
    dataNew = []
    for i in range(1, 8):
        with open(txtNewData.format(i), newline='') as fin:  # read new weather data for a station
            reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
            dataNew.append([(int(year), int(day), float(t1), float(t2), float(p)) for year, day, t1, t2, p, _ in reader])

    # "rows" will return the data of 7 stations for a particular year/day in order.
    # verify all year/day data in the 7 stations match.
    for rows in zip(*dataNew):
        assert all(rows[0][:2] == row[:2] for row in rows)

    # reformat new weather data
    for rows in zip(*dataNew):
        year, day = rows[0][:2]  # take from station 1 since above verified all the same.
        data = []
        for row in rows:
            if TorP == 'T':
                data.extend(row[2:4])  # collect the two temperatures
            elif TorP == 'P':
                data.append(row[4])  # collect the one percipitation
            else:
                raise ValueError("TorP parameter must be 'T' or 'P'")
        # There weren't any <= -99 in the sample data, but checking anyway
        data = [n if n > -99 else -99 for n in data]

        lineOut = f'{year0 + year - 1:04}{day:03}'  # year and day
        lineOut += ''.join([f'{n:05.1f}' for n in data])  # fill in the weather for 7 stations
        dataOld.append(lineOut + '\n')

    # save the data
    with open(txtfout, 'w') as fout:  # write weather data
        fout.writelines(dataOld)

makeSwatInput(r'olddata_T_file.txt', r'newdata_station{}.dat', 'newdata_T_file.txt', 'T')
makeSwatInput(r'olddata_P_file.txt', r'newdata_station{}.dat', 'newdata_P_file.txt', 'P')
```